How to use declarative transaction management in spring cloud task with spring batch
Spring boot 2.5.4
My problem is that i dont't succeed in managing transactions : while i annotate my service layer and dao with @Transactionnal, when i have successive dao call in the same service layer method, every dao call is commited to database instead of that all the calls run in the same transaction.
My Spring Cloud Task setup is below
@EnableTask
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(CoreConfiguration.class)
public class SpringBatchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBatchApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Below, setup for applicative datasource
@Configuration
public class CoreConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean({ "appDatasourceProperties" })
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties appDatasourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean({ "appDataSource" })
    public DataSource appDataSource() {
        return this.appDatasourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean({ "transactionManager" })
    public TransactionManager appTransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(appDataSource());
    }

}

same thing pour scdf server database
@Configuration
@Import(TaskConfiguration.class)
public class DatasourceConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("springCloudDataSource")
  private DataSource springCloudDataSource;
  /**
   * Configuration datasource Spring Cloud Data Flow
   */
  @Override
  @Autowired
  public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("springCloudDataSource") DataSource springCloudDataSource) {
    super.setDataSource(springCloudDataSource);
  }

  /**
   * Configuration initializer Spring Cloud Data Flow
   */
  @Bean
  public BatchDataSourceInitializer batchDataSourceInitializer(
      @Qualifier("springCloudDataSource") DataSource springCloudDataSource,
      ResourceLoader resourceLoader,
      BatchProperties properties) {
    return new BatchDataSourceInitializer(springCloudDataSource, resourceLoader, properties);
  }

  @Override
  protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(springCloudDataSource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(super.getTransactionManager());
    factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
    return factory.getObject();
  }
}

@Configuration
public class TaskConfiguration {

  @Bean({"springCloudDatasourceProperties"})
  @ConfigurationProperties(
      prefix = "spring.datasource"
  )
  public DataSourceProperties springCloudDatasourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }

  @Bean(
      name = {"springCloudDataSource"}
  )
  public DataSource springCloudDatasource() {
    return this.springCloudDatasourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
  }

  @Bean
  public TaskConfigurer taskConfigurer(@Qualifier("springCloudDataSource") DataSource springCloudDatasource) {
    return new DefaultTaskConfigurer(springCloudDatasource);
  }
}

This is an enterprise template, i don't write it. i'm surprised that springCloudDataSource is defined twice in two pieces of configuration but i suppose that it doesn't matters.
I just added the bean transactionManager in the class CoreConfiguration while trying to resolve my problem.
My service layer looks like this :
@Slf4j
@Component
public class FactureRecordingService implements FactureRecording {
    
    @Autowired
    private FactureUploadToAlfresco uploadService;
    
    @Autowired
    private CommonDao common;
    
    @Override
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager", propagation = REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = FactureRecordingFailure.class)
    public RecordingResultDTO recordFacture(File pdf, MetaParsingResultDTO meta) throws FactureRecordingFailure {

        String numeroFacture = meta.getOne().get(MetadataEnum.NUMERO_FACTURE);
        RecordingResultDTO result = new RecordingResultDTO();

        try {
            Long factureId = null;
            FacturePdfDTO facturePdf = null;
            
            /*
             * enregistrement de la facture pdf en base
             */
            facturePdf = common.createFacturePDF(meta.getOne());
            factureId = facturePdf.getId();
            result.setFactureDbId(factureId);
            result.setFacture(facturePdf);
    
            /*
             * certaines factures embarquent n factures
             */
            if (meta.isHasMany()) {
                for (Map<MetadataEnum, String> facture : meta.getMany()) {
                    common.createDetailFacture(factureId, facture);
                }
            }
    
            /*
             * noter que la facture a été chargée pour ne plus jamais la charger
             */
            common.createSpecificRegistreKey(factureId, meta.getOne().get(MetadataEnum.NUMERO_FACTURE));
    
            log.info("Facture {} enregistrée en base sous l'id {}",numeroFacture,factureId);
            
            /*
             * envoi en ged
             * si il échoue, l'exception va se propager et provoquer un rollback de la transaction
             * La facture ne sera pas en base et pourra être chargée à nouveau
             */
            Long gedId = null;
            gedId = uploadService.uploadFacture(pdf,meta.getOne());
            log.info("Facture poussée en GED sous l'id {}",gedId);
            
            result.setFactureGedId(gedId);
            
            return result;

        } catch(ParseException pe) {
            throw new FactureRecordingFailure("Impossible d'enregistrer la facture "+numeroFacture+" en raison d'une date incorrecte",pe);
            
        } catch(UploadFailure e) {
            throw new FactureRecordingFailure("Echec d'upload de la facture "+numeroFacture+" dans la GED",e);
            
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new FactureRecordingFailure("Une erreur est survenue lors de l'enregistrement de la facture "+numeroFacture,ex);
        }
        
        
    }

and my Dao like this
@Component
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class CommonDaoImpl implements CommonDao {
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("appDataSource")
    private DataSource appDataSource;
    
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;
    
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate simpleTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    private FournisseurRules rules;
    
    public FacturePdfDTO createFacturePDF(Map<MetadataEnum,String> data) throws ParseException {
        
        String sql = """
insert into FacturePdf
(typeFacture,numeroFacture,codeFournisseur,dateFacture,typeEnergie,pcl_id,siret,raisonSociale,periodeDebut,periodeFin,montantHT,volume,dateRecuperation,idGed) values 
(:typeFacture,:numeroFacture,:codeFournisseur,:dateFacture,:typeEnergie,:pcl_id,:siret,:raisonSociale,:periodeDebut,:periodeFin,:montantHT,:volume,:dateRecuperation,:idGed) 
                """;

        char typeEnergie = rules.getTypeEnergie().getDbCode();
        String codeFournisseur = rules.getDbCodeFournisseur();
        
        SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("typeFacture",rules.getTypeFacture().getDbCode())
                .addValue("numeroFacture",data.get(MetadataEnum.NUMERO_FACTURE))
                .addValue("codeFournisseur",codeFournisseur)
                .addValue("dateFacture",rules.convertStringToDate(data.get(MetadataEnum.DATE_FACTURE)))
                .addValue("typeEnergie",typeEnergie)
                .addValue("pcl_id", data.get(MetadataEnum.PCL))
                .addValue("siret", data.get(MetadataEnum.SIRET))
                .addValue("raisonSociale",data.get(MetadataEnum.RAISON_SOCIALE))
                .addValue("periodeDebut",rules.convertStringToDate(data.get(MetadataEnum.PERIODE_DEBUT_CONSOMMATION)))
                .addValue("periodeFin",rules.convertStringToDate(data.get(MetadataEnum.PERIODE_FIN_CONSOMMATION)))
                .addValue("montantHT",rules.convertMontantToNumber(data.get(MetadataEnum.MONTANT_HT)))
                .addValue("volume",rules.convertVolumeToNumber(data.get(MetadataEnum.VOLUME)))
                .addValue("dateRecuperation",new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .addValue("idGed",null);
        
        GeneratedKeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        template.update(sql,namedParameters,keyHolder,new String[] { "ID" });

        Long id = keyHolder.getKey().longValue();       
        
        FacturePdfDTO result = new FacturePdfDTO();
        result.setId(id);
        result.setCodeFournisseur(codeFournisseur);
        result.setTypeEnergie(typeEnergie);
        
        return result;
        
    }


Problem : after createFacturePDF call, the data inserted by the dao code is allready commited.  spring makes a commit somewhere
My expectation was that the commit arrives only when the recordFacture terminate without error.
I suppose that i made a big error somewhere but i can't figure where

After some research, i found that the difficulty with bootstrapping Spring Cloud Task + Sprint Batch with a different datasource than application is well known. There is quite a lot of post about this subject. Sometimes Spring Boot is somewhat confusing.
i totally rewrite the @Configuration and i doon't have any problem now.
i have to analyze more in depth the enterprise pattern to understand where is the problem but that's probably the appTransationManager which is not tied to the right datasource.
